# xmodmap Mode_switch for different layouts

Tags: keyboard-layout, vim, xmodmap, capslock

I need to add the same "Mode_switch layer" triggered by Caps_Lock for both layouts: EN and RU.

Specifically,

- both `Caps_Lock + h` and `Capd_Lock + р` *(Cyrillic_er)* should lead to `Left`;
- both `Caps_Lock + l` and `Capd_Lock + д` *(Cyrillic_de)* should lead to `Right`;

etc. (like vim-style)

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434143) helped me to do this thing for my EN layout but it has a side effect on the RU layout. For example:

```
! this is my .Xmodmap file

  keycode 66 = Mode_switch

! keysym   l = l L             Cyrillic_de Cyrillic_DE l     L
  keysym   l = l L Right Right Cyrillic_de Cyrillic_DE Right Right
```

This causes `Cyrillic_de` to trigger `Right` instead of `Cyrillic_de` itself.
As I understand, Mode_switch works with groups of two elements, so in my example we have:
`l L`, `Right Right`, `Cyrillic_de Cyrillic_DE`, `Right Right`.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to make Mode_switch work with groups of four elements: `l L Right Right` and `Cyrillic_de Cyrillic_DE Right Right`?
2. Are there any other workarounds to reach my goal without xmodmap?

Thanks in advance!